# Get screen width and calculate max value

Tags: css, less

I have code like the below where I want to calculate and assign values for the `font-size`/`height` properties. In this I want to set the value of a property (say `max-height`) based on the maximum of available screen `height` and a calculated value (lets assume like the calculation done for the `height` property). Is there any way to do this in LESS? I tried with the `max` function but it doesn't seem to work.

Also, for assigning px/em etc to the value, in one of the threads it is mentioned that it can be done using 0em + variable value. But is there a better looking way to do this? I tried like the second way shown in the below code but it is not working.

The usecase mentioned here might sound silly but the actual cases are different and I have mentioned it this way only for simplicity.

```
.def(@fSize){
  @defHeight: 100px; // Need this to be screen width
  font-size: 0em + @fSize;
  line-height: 0px + (1.5*@fSize); 
  height: 0px + (15*@fSize); // Works fine
  //height: ~"15*@{fSize}px"; // Just prints 15*1px
  max-height: max(@defHeight, @fSize) // doesn't work
}

div#demo{
  .def(1);
}
```

Comment: I guess what you're trying to achieve is called [element query](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/element-query-workarounds.html)

Comment: Speaking of numbers and units. There's [`unit`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-unit) function for manipulating number units. But for this specific snippet using "arithmetic ops unit propagation" is probably more elegant. Although, in this particular case, for a bit more readable (semantically) code you should use multiplication instead of addition , i.e.: `font-size: 1em * @fSize;`, `height: 15px * @fSize;` etc. (`@fSize` is just a scale and the scale is just the arithmetic multiply).

Comment: @seven-phases-max thanks, will use that approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiple questions there, so will answer them one by one.

1. Yes, you can get the available screen height just like you would do in plain JavaScript using `window.screen.availWidth`. LESS supports Javascript statements when provided within **backticks**.
2. For getting the maximum among two values you can use the built-in `max()` function in Less like `max(@var1, @var2)`. In this `@var1` and `@var2` are the two values for comparison. Note that **both of them should be in the same unit** for comparison. If not it will just output `max(val1, val2)` as output (which is what is happening in your case).
3. For assigning the unit, that was one of the ways for earlier versions of LESS. Now it has a built in function called `unit()` which can be  used like `unit(@var,px)`. This function actually works pretty much the same way like `~"15*@{fSize}px"` (Note the backticks within the quotes, this is why your second height property didn't work).

Overall, your code can be done as follows:

```
.def(@fSize){
  @defHeight: `window.screen.availHeight`; //This is for getting screen width
  font-size: unit(@fSize, em); // The following are for assigning the units
  line-height: unit(1.5*@fSize,px);
  height: unit(15*@fSize,px);
  max-height: max(unit(@defHeight,px),unit(15*@fSize,px)) // This is for comparison
}

div#demo{
  .def(1);
}
```

**Compiled Output:**

```
div#demo {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5px;
  height: 15px;
  max-height: 900px;
}
```